# Ebay API. Translate

Tags: ebay-api

I use ebay API. Products get to the location US `siteId = 0`, so that everything goes back to English (the category and products).

Searched API for translation in the official documentation, found nothing.

Question: how to get the products and categories in Russian language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little old question but..

eBay does not automatically translate its categories according to the siteId.

there are several eBay marketplaces [see here](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/concepts/siteidtoglobalid.html)

and each has its own categories and its **category version** (means that some categories found in siteId==0 are not available in other siteId) that can be retrieved via [getCategories](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetCategories.html)

then there are "real" translation APIs
but that's another kind of services:
[Translaion APIs](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/translation/overview.html)